# Trying to import ec2 instance using Terraformer getting this error --> expected: IDENT | STRING | ASSIGN | LBRACE got: NUMBER

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, hashicorp

**verbose of the import command**

`2022/04/28 14:20:26 Filtered number of resources for service ec2_instance: 63 2022/04/28 14:20:26 aws Connecting....  2022/04/28 14:20:26 aws save ec2_instance 2022-04-28T14:20:26.303+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.stdio: received EOF, stopping recv loop: err="rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = error reading from server: EOF" 2022-04-28T14:20:26.309+0530 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin process exited: path=/home/shivangi/.terraform.d/plugins/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-aws_v4.11.0_x5 pid=53373 2022-04-28T14:20:26.309+0530 [DEBUG] plugin: plugin exited 2022/04/28 14:20:26 At 443:5: expected: IDENT | STRING | ASSIGN | LBRACE got: NUMBER`

> Terraform version -> Terraform v1.1.9 on linux_amd64
> aws provider plugin version -> terraform-provider-aws_v4.11.0_x5
> Terraformer version -> version v0.8.19

This issue is occurring for the azure network interface and other resources too.

Comment: What command are you using to run terraformer and what does the configuration of your providers look like?

Comment: I have used "terraformer import aws --resources=ec2_instance --regions=ap-south-1 --verbose"
Provider configuration -> 
provider "aws" {
  region = "ap-south-1"
}

terraform {
 required_providers {
  aws = {
     version = "~> 4.11.0"
  }
  }
}

Comment: I have looked into it ,due to one ec2 it is giving error and not saving the tfstate file for others.